# Don't seem to get $().attr('src') to do its job

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First post here, so please be gentle ;-)

I've been learning coding over the last couple of weeks by making a dummy page, and been implementing what i learn on it incrementaly as i progress, hence it's a mixed bag where the functionality/code is according to when i wrote it, based on pure html/CSS, inline javascript, external javascript, and finally jquery.

So i mostly wrapped it up and i'm now cleaning up the mess, and part of my mission is to cull functions and lines of codes, and in one of them i'm kind of stuck.

The before was 30 buttons calling to 30 different functions onclick like so:

```
function cell3() {

         document.getElementById('base3').src='images/1/3/' + x + '.png';
         document.getElementById('base3b').src='images/1/3/' + x + '.png';
         document.getElementById('v2base3').src='images/2/3/' + x + '.png';
         document.getElementById('v2base3b').src='images/2/3/' + x + '.png';
         document.getElementById('cell3').style.backgroundColor= x ;
}
```

Where a global variable (x) defines the folder paths for images to replace the images within some divs when clicking the button (cell3). It also changes the bGroung color of it. Sorry if the naming is a bit confusing...

So i'm removing all 30 functions and the 30 onclick calls with this bit of jquery:

```
$('button').click(function(){

  var eyeD = $(this).attr("id"); 
  var newURLa = 'images/1/' + eyeD + '/' + x + '.png';
  var newURLb = 'images/2/' + eyeD + '/' + x + '.png';

    $('base' + eyeD).attr('src', newURLa);
    $('base' + eyeD + 'b').attr('src', newURLa);
    $('v2base' + eyeD).attr('src', newURLb);
    $('v2base' + eyeD + 'b').attr('src', newURLb);
    $(this).css( "background-color", x );
    document.getElementsByid('check').innerhtml = eyeD;

});
```

For that to 'work' i changed the button's names from 'cell1', 'cell2, etc. to '1', '2', etc.

Now the thing is, when clicking on the buttons the var 'eyeD' takes the value from the button ok. ('1', '2', etc.). The elements ID's are formed correctly ('base1', 'base2'... 'base1b', base2b'...), and the URL's are formed correctly. (The last line in the code is a p element that displays values so i could try to troubleshoot it) The background color also changes as expected. But the images do not get replaced.

Tried adding commas to the resulting URL's in case it was a syntax issue, but nothing happens. i even went freestyle and tried it with the =url() on it, different commas in different places, etc. So basically scraping the barrel here. Also wrote a url without variables to see if that would work, but still nothing. Also getting no errors when looking at the console.

It's probably a basic 'DOH!' thing, but right now i have a mental block...

Also, is there a way to keep the original naming and just retrieve the numbering part of the ID's? Thought about using the [4] identifier to get the 5th digit, but that won't work when running double digit numbers. (10, 11, etc)

Thanks!

Comment: `$("ID")` is incorrect.  It should be `$("#ID")`

Comment: So close.... `$('base' + eyeD).` should be `$('#base' + eyeD).` along with all the other ids.

Comment: Just gave that a try. Still doesn't work. I haven't used the # for a while and have had no issues, so either it's not necesary anymore or i'm going to have to spend a few hours adding the # to all the functions that call elements by id's... :-) Thanks BTW

Comment: Um without the "#" it means you are looking for an `<base1></base1>` element

Comment: Forgot to mention, it works perfect with the pure JS. so the 'old' code above (without the ) works good.

Comment: A good complement for learning jQuery is CSS.  For instance, to apply styles to an element with id "base" your CSS is `#base {/*styles*/}`.  To select the same element in jQuery, the selector is the same: `$("#base")`.

Comment: Have you attached the listener to the buttons on page load? like `$(document).ready(function () { /* your code above with id fixes */ });`

Comment: Your plain javascript works without the `#` because that's the syntax for plain JavaScript.  If you want to select an element in jQuery by its id, you do so with the #:  `$("#id")`.

Comment: There is no `document.getElementsByid` method either. Ids are singular. You can not have more than one element with the same id.

Comment: Dave Goten. Yes, the function is within  the ready(function. This latest bit of code is part of a .js with 300 lines of jquery, all of which works ok. Also tried it independently, and the results are the same.

Comment: epascarello. Yes, that s was removed. I mistyped it in sublime once and now gets thrown by the 'predictive text' thing every time. Ha, ha

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery lines accessing the elements are missing the `#` sign.

Change these...

```
$('base' + eyeD).attr('src', newURLa);
```

To this...

```
$('#base' + eyeD).attr('src', newURLa);
```

Also, your last line where you use plain JS, can be done in jQuery as well with less code.

```
document.getElementsByid('check').innerhtml = eyeD;
```

To...

```
$("#check").html(eyeD);
```

However, you should always use distinct ID's for elements.  If you need to use multiple elements at the same time, use a class instead.

```
$(".check").html(eyeD);
```

Comment: Yeah, that last line was a quick copy and paste form another element that was on the page already, so they share the pure JS and class, hence i named it 'check'

Answer (score 0):

You're grabbing an element incorrectly.

Either Grab an element by it's class name like so:

```
$('.v2base' + eyeD + 'b').attr('src', newURLb);
```

Or by its ID:

```
$('#v2base' + eyeD + 'b').attr('src', newURLb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!! It was indeed calling the id with the hash, but also it has to be called with double quotation marks. Single inverted commas won't work.

So the working format is

```
$("#v2base" + eyeD + "b")
```

but it won't work like so

```
$('#v2base' + eyeD + 'b')
```

Thanks everyone, it's been emotional